# Is disk's UUID a good identifier for disk?

Tags: hard-drive, uuid

My tool working among 100 disks, some of them may attach or detach from the server during the tool running. I want to use disk's UUID as disk's id, and I got the question: If some disk `disk_1` got a UUID, say `32c8da8b-e6d5-9a85-5cfc-1a8b59535263`. When it's space full, I detached the disk and formatted it (`mkfs.ext3`), then re-attach to machine, will it's UUID change?

Comment: What's your tool?

Answer (score 3):

A filesystem's UUID is generated by mkfs, so a reformat will change the UUID.

One option is to create a label when you make the filesystem and look in `/dev/disk/by-label` rather than `/dev/disk/by-uuid`. An advantage of using a label is that you can re-label a filesystem after the fact if you need to. A disadvantage is that you are now responsible for maintaining the labels and preventing collisions.

Comment: The first part is right, the UUID will change.  But I'm not sure a label is a good id.  There is a limit to the number of characters a label may have, so ensuring uniqueness would require some discipline.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no specific reason for exclusively using UUID, you might consider alternatives like using `/dev/disk/by-partuuid`.
It relies on information stored in the GPT rather than in the partition itself, so the identifier should remain fixed when you only reformat the partition.

`/dev/disk/by-id` might also be interesting, it uses the hardware serial number. However, the controller type is part of the ID-string, so that might be a problem if you attach your disks differently each time.

source:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming